# %let %put variables - what it does to your sas program

Tags: sas

I'm new in SAS. I'd like to know what the lines below do. Couldn't figure out what it does to the program because I didn't encounter any of the defined variables in the succeeding parts after declaration.

```
%let cutofftime  =%sysfunc(time());
%let currdt      = %sysfunc(putn(&cutofftime.,time5.)) ; 
%put &cutofftime. &currdt.;
```

Comment: If the macro variables are never referenced then the lines are probably just there to write the execution time into the log.

Answer (score 3):

The %let statement is used to create a macro variable.

The first statement:

```
%let cutofftime  =%sysfunc(time());
```

uses the time() function to determine the current time.   It returns the current time as a numeric value which is number of seconds since midnight.

The second statement:

```
%let currdt      = %sysfunc(putn(&cutofftime.,time5.)) ;
```

uses the PUTN() to convert the numeric time value (which Is now stored in the macro variable CUTOFFTIME) to a pretty formatted value like 22:30.

So after the two %let statements have run, you created two macro variables. Then the %PUT statement is used to write the values of the two macro variables to the log:

```
%put &cutofftime. &currdt.;
```

Using the %PUT statement to write the value of macro variables to the log is a useful way to  debug macro code, in the same way that the PUT statement can be used to write the value of data step variables to the log as a data step debugging tool. When I run the code at 9:32 PM, the log shows:

```
3    %put &cutofftime. &currdt.;
77537.809 21:32
```

That said, if you're new to SAS, you should probably avoid the trying to learn the macro language at the same time as you are learning the SAS language.

Comment: Thank you, Quentin! I'll take note of that! :)